# Are there any known HTA file Security Issues?

Tags: javascript, security, hta

Are there any known security issues related to running a web application via a .hta file.  I am especially interested in the drag & drop issues related to .hta files and frames

see: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/01/10/drag-and-drop-problems-in-hta-frames.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on whether you mean current (unpatched) vulnerabilities, or vulnerabilities since HTML Applications were first introduced? See [this](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=vulnerability+ie+HTA&spell=1) Google search for examples of the latter. You should also check if HTAs are still going to be supported in future versions of Windows/IE.